# How to configure Tor browser without Vidalia on Mac OS X?

Tags: configuration

I have a problem with finding a configuration file for my downloaded Tor browser bundle (the default installation from project webpage). I want to adjust some advanced settings for my Tor browser, and as of today, Vidalia is no longer available. What should I do? I also installed command-line version with macports, but how the default Mac OS X Tor app and command-line version interact? What I want to achieve is to have adjusted advanced settings in my default Tor app with GUI since I am not very familiar with browsing web via command-line tool.

I searched for such issue on stack exchange, but found none.

I would be grateful for assistance on this.